# Why am I getting this error when I sue the solution posted for how to use a picklist field in a formula field

Tags: formula, picklist, fields

Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number

The formula content is this: I need to pull together the Tracking # + the Case # + the Pickup Type__c, which is a picklist of 3 different values:

Tracking_Number__c +  CaseNumber + value(text(Pickup_Type__c))

Answer (score 1):

Because `VALUE()` takes a string and turns it into a number, and `string + string + number` makes no sense as a formula (i.e. it's a syntax error).

The `+` operator in functions can be used for both string concatenation as well as addition (on numbers). If you want to concatenate strings together, I'd recommend instead using the `&` operator so that things are more clear.

Remove the `VALUE()` from the last part of your formula (so that it's just `TEXT(Pickup_Type__c)`) and it should work. You probably want to include a separator between each of the 3 things you're concatenating as well. Otherwise, it's probably going to be hard for people (or code) to tell when the tracking number ends and the case number starts.

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you!  I was using the instructions from the other article and thought I tried the text option but I must have not done it correctly.